Is it possible to use Ajax in Blazor Static SSR mode?
I started to use Blazor server side with Static SSR mode, and with the help of <PageScript /> component and its onupdate method running js, and also server-side databinding and use of HttpContext facilities, it is very similar to ASP.NET Core MVC except that we have components.
Since with this mode we break free from SignalR and use Blazor serverside like a traditional serverside framework, it is good. But it lacks one important thing that is Ajax.
Is there any way to do jQuery ajax or any other form of ajax in Blazor server Static SSR mode?

All Javascript is available in Blazor, whatever your server mode, since Javascript is always client-side.

using unobtrusive ajax in a page child component: <form @onsubmit="SubmitAjax" @formname="ajax-form" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post"  data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#ajax-update" data-ajax-loading="#loading"> it works but replaces the full  page in the place holder. is there any way to return or update part of the page (only the child component)?

I don't see the benefit of "breaking free" of signalR, but then using Ajax to communicate with your server asynchronously.  Standard Blazor in interactive server mode (or auto) would be much better IMO.
